# Failed to add labels in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

Given a data set "factorData005.fact", how to get this graph?

```
[1] one star    three stars zero star   four stars  three stars three stars zero star  
 [8] four stars  one star    zero star   three stars four stars  three stars zero star  
 [15] three stars three stars one star    one star    three stars four stars  four stars 
 [22] zero star   three stars four stars  four stars  zero star   one star    zero star  
 [29] zero star   three stars zero star   three stars zero star   zero star   zero star  
 [36] three stars three stars zero star   three stars zero star   zero star   zero star  
 [43] zero star   four stars  zero star   three stars four stars  zero star   three stars
 [50] zero star   four stars  zero star   three stars four stars  three stars three stars
 [57] zero star   three stars zero star   four stars  three stars one star    four stars 
 [64] three stars zero star   four stars  zero star   zero star   zero star   zero star  
 [71] three stars three stars three stars four stars  zero star   four stars  zero star  
 [78] three stars four stars  zero star   zero star   zero star   three stars three stars
 [85] three stars three stars zero star   three stars four stars  three stars one star   
 [92] three stars three stars zero star   four stars  three stars zero star   zero star  
 [99] three stars zero star  
Levels: zero star three stars four stars one star
```

```
factorData005.fact <- factor(factorData005.fact, levels = c("zero star", "three stars", "four stars", "one star"))
df <- data.frame(value = factorData005.fact)
p3 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=value)) + 
  geom_bar(fill=c("red", "green", "cyan", "purple")) + 
  scale_shape_manual(labels=c("zero star", "three stars", "four stars", "one star"))
print(p3)
```

Above is my code. The labels are not added successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Recreate your data (random distribution)

```r
zero_to_three <- c("zero", "one", "two", "three")
zero_to_three_stars <- paste(zero_to_three, "star")

factorData005.fact <-
  factor(sample(zero_to_three_stars, 100, replace = TRUE),
         levels = zero_to_three_stars)

df <- data.frame(value = factorData005.fact)
```

Calculate frequencies with `dplyr::count()`. This allows the placement of
labels on top of the bars.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_count <-
  df |>
  count(value)
```

We can add labels to the plot with `geom_text()` or `geom_label()`.
To specify a custom color palette in `ggplot2` use `scale_fill_manual()`.

Plot with labels.

```r
ggplot(df_count, aes(x = value, y = n, fill = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green", "cyan", "purple")) +
  geom_text(aes(y = n + 1, label = value))
```

[image]

Plot with frequencies as labels.

```r
ggplot(df_count, aes(x = value, y = n, fill = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green", "cyan", "purple")) +
  geom_label(aes(y = n + 1, label = n))
```

[image]

You can use `reorder()` on the `x` argument, to arrange the bars by
frequency.

```r
ggplot(df_count, aes(x = reorder(value, -n), y = n, fill = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green", "cyan", "purple")) +
  geom_text(aes(y = n + 1, label = n))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=value)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill=value)) + # you need to wrap into aes()
  scale_fill_discrete(labels=c("zero star", "three stars", "four stars", "one star"), name = "fact")+ # use scale_fill_* for your legend; name sets the legend title
  labs(title = "A.factorData005.fact") # adding title
```

[image]